# ST_ApproximateMedialAxis returns multilinestring instead of single linestring

Tags: postgis

`ST_ApproximateMedialAxis` on POLYGON returns MULTILINESTRING. Shouldn't it be just single LINESTRING?

We use Postgres 11 + PostGIS 2.5.0 (Geos 3.7.0), SFCGAL 1.3.6 (CGAL 4.13), pgrouting 2.6.1.

Please see attached image with the visualization of the input polygon (blue) and output (red).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis), the "The medial axis of an object is the set of all points having more than one closest point on the object's boundary." This is a fairly dense definition, but it essentially means that the linestrings connecting the points are equidistant between the edges of the enclosing polygon. A few examples might help to illustrate the point.

1. The medial axis of a circle, is a single point, the center, as this point is equidistant to every point on the exterior.
2. The medial axis of a triangle is three lines from each vertex to the center point.

   [image]
3. For a more complex shape, see you own example, or the example from the [scikit-learn skeletonize library](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html), which has the skeleton of a horse, where any extrusion in the boundary has a corresponding spur in the medial axis.

[image]

So, in fact, the only shape I can think of that would return a single LINESTRING as its medial axis, would be a bacillus shape.

Unfortunately, my attempts to demonstrate this using Postgis have been unsuccessful, as, a MultiLinestring is always returned, whether with ST_ApproximateMedialAxis or ST_StraightSkeleton, eg,

```
SELECT AS_AsText(
          ST_StraightSkeleton(
                ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)')
                , 2, 'endcap=round')
          )
);
```

the buffer of a linestring with a rounded encap, is a bacillus shape, but this returns:

> MULTILINESTRING((8.5857864376269 11.4142135623731,9.93052414277937 9.93052414277937),(-1.41421356237309 1.41421356237309,0.069475857220631 0.069475857220631),(-1.66293922460509 1.1111404660392,0 0),(-1.84775906502257 0.765366864730177,0 0),(-1.9
>   6157056080646 0.390180644032253,0 0),(-2 0,0 0),(-1.96157056080646 -0.390180644032259,0 0),(-1.84775906502257 -0.765366864730181,0 0),(-1.66293922460509 -1.11114046603921,0 0),(-1.41421356237309 -1.4142135623731,0 0),(-1.1111404660392 -1.66293922
>   460509,0 0),(-0.76536686473018 -1.84775906502257,0 0) ...

This, in no way undermines the answer, but points more to the fact that a buffer is an approximation, and the skeleton/medial axis is therefore subject to rounding errors.

**EDIT:** The definition of the difference between the medial axis and the skeleton is somewhat nebulous, see, for example, the skeleton definition from wikipedia: "
The shrinking process, the straight skeleton (blue) and the roof model.
In geometry, a straight skeleton is a method of representing a polygon by a topological skeleton. It is similar in some ways to the medial axis but differs in that the skeleton is composed of straight line segments, while the medial axis of a polygon may involve parabolic curves". This, definition clearly means in 3D, but, nevertheless, there is not a one to one mapping between them. Nevertheless, the medial axis will still, in most cases, return a MultiLinestring, as in the Postgis docs, except in the case of a trivial regular polygon, such as a rectangle. [image]

In the case of a rectangle, the Skeleton, is a MultiLinestring,

```
SELECT ST_Astext(ST_StraightSkeleton(ST_Expand(ST_Makepoint(0, 0), 2, 10)));
```

> MULTILINESTRING((-2 -10,0 -8),(2 -10,0 -8),(2 10,0 8),(-2 10,0 8),(0 -8,0 8))

whereas the medial axis is a single LineString, even though, it is return as a MultiLinestring.

```
SELECT ST_Astext(ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(ST_Expand(ST_Makepoint(0, 0), 2, 10)));
```

> MULTILINESTRING((0 -8,0 8))

This is all rather nebulous and unsatisfactory, and, the big take away would seem to be that the word **approximate** is relevant, and that, broadly speaking, unless the shape is trivially regular, you will never get a single LineString back.

**EDIT 2:** From he actual definition of ST_ApproximateMedialAxis in the [sfcgal source code](https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/blob/e098b6b30c4ff5e5478b6132be5fcd1fa2b14731/src/algorithm/straightSkeleton.cpp#L346).
Note  that the return type is defined to be

> std::auto_ptr< MultiLineString > mx( new MultiLineString );

after which the straight skeleton is calculated. Finally, the function, [skeletonToMedialAxis](https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/blob/e098b6b30c4ff5e5478b6132be5fcd1fa2b14731/src/algorithm/straightSkeleton.cpp#L117) is called, which removes all angles of greater than 45 degrees, between the calculated skeleton and the original polygon edge. This explains both why it is always a MultiLinestring, but, also, why you don't get a single connected linestring back.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it to me. I was confused by image at https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html when compared to https://postgis.net/docs/ST_StraightSkeleton.html. So now what I need is to extract the longest linestring from that multiline string. My intent is to render mountain range names across them.

Comment: That should work for an object, so long as the minimum bounding rectangle is clearly not a regular polygon. You will probably need to merge the linestrings together in order to extract the longest. If the answer has helped, please accept it.

Comment: No, wait, you are correct. The answer needs clarification.

Comment: BTW in your example you used `ST_StraightSkeleton` instead of `ST_ApproximateMedialAxis`. Not sure if that was an intent.

Comment: Yes, I was attempting to show a case where it would be a single linestring, a bacillus, but failed. However, the difference between a straight skeleton and the medial axis of a rectangle, does show this difference. Just writing that up.

Comment: That was quite an interesting bit of investigation. I have been looking at the SFCGAL code recently. I never thought I would see the skeleton of a horse and a  bacillus before breakfast, but, there it is.