# Break medial axis into a set of simple polylines using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, medial-axis

The medial axis for a polygon computed by ST_ApproximateMedialAxis() is usually a single `MultiLineString` with possibly many branches (see e.g. [ST_ApproximateMedialAxis returns multilinestring instead of single linestring](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312283)). In other words, it's often a tree or network compressed into a single multigeometry. And the monolithic geometry is quite difficult to analyze.

Is there a way in PostGIS to break the MultiLineString representation of medial axis into a small set of simple LineStrings?

(In a way, this is similar to ArcHydro's [stream link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/stream-link.htm) function, but instead of breaking down a raster network into links, break down a compressed multi-linestring network into links)

-- Edit --

To detail the issue, below is a test medial axis generated by PostGIS. I'd like to extract the handful (~ 10) segments each as a simple polyline:

[image]

But it seems that the multi-linestring from ST_ApproximateMedialAxis() is composed of a very large number of two-node parts, each corresponding to one segment of the zigzag shape of the zoomed-in view below:

[image]

The number of points in the multi-linestring is exactly twice the number of parts:

```
SELECT ST_NumGeometries(geom), ST_NPoints(geom) FROM road_line;

 st_numgeometries | st_npoints 
------------------+------------
             6188 |      12376
(1 row)
```

`ST_Dump` (as suggested in the answers) generates a very large (too large) number of two-node LineString's.

Comment: You can use `ST_LineMerge` to connect 2-point lines into longer runs between actual nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decomposing `MULTILINESTRINGS` into simple `LINESTRING`s - or any `MULTI` geometry or `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` into their simple parts and components - is trivial with `ST_Dump`:

- using (`CROSS JOIN`) `LATERAL` set decomposition over processed rows:

  ```
  SELECT
    <id>,
    dmp.path[1] AS sid,
    dmp.geom
  FROM
    <polygon_table>,
    LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(geom)) AS dmp
  ;
  ```
- same `LATERAL` set decomposition on a sub-query - using a grouped `ST_Union` as example:

  ```
  SELECT
    <id>,
    dmp.path[1] AS sid,
    dmp.geom
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        <id>,
        ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(ST_Union(geom)) AS ama
      FROM
        <polygon_table>
      GROUP BY
        <id>
    ) AS q,
    LATERAL ST_Dump(ama) AS dmp
  ;
  ```
- using composite type columnar accessors:

  ```
  SELECT
    (
      ST_Dump(
        ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(geom)
      )
    ).*
  FROM
    <polygon_table>
  ;
  ```